# How do i use document.getElementById("mydiv") to edit multiple divs with the same ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

What I have is

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("post").style.backgroundColor="#ECF6A4";
}
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change Post Color</button>
```

In the page there are multiple divs with the id="post" but when I save the code and try it out it only changes the background of the first div on the page with the id="post" and not any of the others.

I tried getElementsById with no luck, thats all I could think of.

Any simple fixes for this?

Comment: Yes, change the IDs to classes and use `getElementsByClassName()`. You're *not* supposed to have multiple elements sharing the same ID.

Comment: ID is ment to be uniq.

Comment: I am trying getElementsByClassName() but nothing changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use class instead of id when you want to reference multiple elements.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class').style.backgroundColor = "#ECF6A4"
```

Comment: `.style.backgroundColor`? don't think it works that way for a nodeList.

Comment: you're right I thought it could be like jQuery `$('.class').css('backgroundColor','yellow');`

Answer (score 2):

Multiple divs with the same id on the same page is invalid markup, duplicate id´s are not valid.

so use classes pls
and therefore

```
getElementsByClassName()
```

to iterate over them

Answer (score 1):

Since i already [finished my demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/mN8KpK?p=preview)

You wrote: `trying getElementsByClassName() but nothing changes` the reason for this is that `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array and you have to access each element of this array before you can use `.style.backgroundColor="#ECF6A4";`

```
function myFunction()
{
    var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName("even");
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++)
    {
        listItems[i].style.backgroundColor="#ECF6A4"; // element i of array
    }
}
```

And the html

```
<ul>
  <li class="odd">1</li>
  <li class="even">2</li>
  <li class="odd">3</li>
  <li class="even">4</li>
  <li class="odd">5</li>
  <li class="even">6</li>      
</ul>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change Color for even</button>
```